# How to delete an outlet from my storyboard?

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I duplicated a .xib file and a swift file to adapt to another view quickly. But now from my initial .xib there all my outlets (from this view) have 2 components (the initial and the new created):

[image]

How can I remove a link in my case?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Connections inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With right clicking on the object and then click on `x`.

[image]

Or from the connection inspector in the right hand side of the Xcode:

[image]

Comment: perfect! Thank you very much!